# (another) request for clarification about the meaning of "singleton" in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, singleton

I'm learning angular, experimenting with different ways of using services/factories, and am trying to wrap my head around the unique sense in which they are "singletons".

I have an `API` service that exposes domain models and wraps functionality for retrieving  them from my REST server. This service can be easily comprehended as a singleton in the classic sense: I want a single instance to be shared across my application, with a state  that can be observed by many different controllers, enabling those controllers to  "synchronize" with each other *through the conduit of the service*: The controllers stay in sync not by being aware of (and thus coupled with) each other directly, but by being aware of this common service. (side question: is this a correct characterization of the role of a service?)

This is a use-case where a singleton service is clearly and unambiguously appropriate. But:

One of the domain objects that gets returned by the `API` service is called `thread`, which is essentially a wrapper around a linked-list of `point`s. In addition to the list of points, a thread has a `currentPoint` variable and a `next()` function, which pops the next value from the list and makes it the `currentPoint`.

My UI visualizes a thread simultaneously in two different ways - in two separate elements with their own controllers and directives. Each of these elements contains a button that, when clicked, calls `nextPoint()` and thereby changes the state of the thread. When this button is pushed in one element, the state of the thread needs to be updated in both elements - so, here again we have a situation where a service seems ideal.

But, at any given time, there can be an arbitrary number of threads being displayed, each of which should be independent and unaware of each other - which conflicts with (what I understand to be) the "classic" sense of "singleton".

**Is there a word for this sort of thing in angular?**

I've experimented/looked into this enough to know that it's certainly possible to create these "non-singleton singletons" using `factory`s, but surely there must be a better term for them than "non-singleton singletons" - I cringed both times I just typed it.

Second, **what is the best way of implementing one?** Can the strategy illustrated below (which I found in an angular github issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1011)) be regarded as a best practice?

```
myApp.factory('myServiceProvider',function(){
    var serviceProvider=function(){};
    serviceProvider.prototype.foo=function(){};

    var service = {
        getInstance:function(){ return new serviceProvider(); }
    }

    return service;
});

//Singleton Services
myApp.factory('myService',['myServiceProvider',function(myServiceProvider){
    return myServiceProvider.getInstance();
}]);

//Where non-singletons are required
function myController(myServiceProvider){
    var instance_a=myServiceProvider.getInstance();
    var instance_b=myServiceProvider.getInstance();
};

//Where singleton service is required
function myOtherController(myService){
    myService.foo();
};
```

Comment: i find that EventEmitters are great at gluing together disparate pieces of code that need to react to changes/happenings in a coordinated yet independent fashion. angular has $scope.on/emit, so it's an option you already have available. you just emit when something changes, and subscribe where you need change notification. the two code fragments are not connected otherwise. EE's are typically singletons in a classic sense. just my $0.02...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An angular singleton is not exactly the classic. A singleton in angular is basically one instance of an object that holds a single state.  That state can be data bindable via a services allowing for value sharing.  This means that you can have a service property that is bound across all of its uses an app; one change will be reflected everywhere.  The singleton persists through the life of the app. If the app is refreshed the singleton will loose value until it is set again by the app via a user interaction or a storage retrieval.

I like the pattern you are using.  I also tend to use it.  Here is an example of a web storage service I recently made similar to your service, https://github.com/breck421/WebStorage/blob/master/src/js/WebStorage.js.

I hope this helps and feel free to continue this dialog :)

Thanks,

Jordan

Comment: hey - wanted to thank you for your answer and the link, I appreciated both. Will accept / respond tomorrow when I'll have more time :)